# Kill display manager and start another one with a script

Tags: shell, xorg, kill

I have a small script in which I kill gdm3 and start up an X Session. It works, but I have to run it 3 times.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
var = $(pidof gdm3)
kill $(var)
X :0 &
xterm &
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

What shall I do to make it work in one run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with father and child processes. When gdm3 starts - given your scripts needs to run thrice - it suggests there are one father and two child processes.

Try editing your script to a loop; something like this:

**export DISPLAY=:0
var = $(pidof gdm3)
while [ ! -z "$var" ]
do
  kill $(var)
  var = $(pidof gdm3)
done
X :0 &
xterm &
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so**

Comment: you're right, i had to kill gdm3 multiple times. I made my script kill gdm3 2 times in a row now, and it works. But if i start a gdm3 session again and execute the script, the script doesn't execute all my commands - breaks up after the simple kill gdm3 command. So i have to run the script multiple times. In that case, your code is helpful. I didn't thought about just running it in a loop. I thought, when i do kill or killall on a process, the programm should stop - that's why i asked. Thanks!